# No image from plot in igraph-python

Tags: python, plot, igraph, graph-visualization

I am loading an edge list file in [python-igraph](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-igraph) and try to plot it. After the plot command 
the image viewer opens saying

```
No images found in 'file:///tmp/igraph6zGOpj.png
```

The commands are as follows

```
g = Graph.Read_Ncol("network.json",names = True)
layout = g.layout("kk")
plot(g,layout = layout)
```

Comment: first off you have typo in the world 'layout' in the third line.

Comment: Probably a platform-specific issue; basically, igraph creates the plot in a temporary file and then forwards it to an image viewer. In your case, either the temporary image disappears before the image viewer has a chance to read it, or igraph is passing it to a wrong image viewer. Which platform are you using?

Comment: @Tamas I am using Ubuntu

Comment: Haven't seen this behaviour on Ubuntu yet; I know that we had to work around this on Windows and Mac OS X. Nevertheless, can you try this: `from igraph import Plot; pl=Plot(); pl.add(g, layout=layout); pl._windows_hacks=True; pl.show()` . This will wait 5 seconds after the creation of the temporary file to give the image viewer a chance to read it before the temporary file is removed from the disk.